# How To Add Colour To The Field With IIF Statement In Acess Queries Conditions

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query condition as shown:

`IIf([Status]="ACTIVE";"ACTIVE";IIf([Cancellation_date]<Now() Or IsNull([Cancellation_date]);"Cancelled ";"To be cancelled on " & [Cancellation_date] & ""))`

Additionally, I would like the fields to be of some colours. Of course, I would like the text to be shown there too.
 green, if `"ACTIVE"` 
 orange if `"To be cancelled on " & [Cancellation_date] & "` 
 red if `[Cancellation_date]<Now() Or IsNull([Cancellation_date])`.

Please, how can I achieve this? The statement is currently working but I am left with the colouring part.

Thank you for the support

Comment: @Warcupine yes it is.

Comment: is this in a query itself, or a form with a query as the recordset?

Comment: It is a query itself.

Comment: You cannot color cells inside a query. You would need to make a form set the query as the recordset and then apply conditional formatting to the controls you want formatted.

Comment: Yes a form is currenly using it but i dont know how to do the conditional formating of the control based on the certain condition that it displays

Comment: your help would come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your form in design view and click on the first control you want to format.

In the banner go to Format under Form Design Tools.

Click Conditional Formatting, then New Rule.

Make sure Green is higher in the list than Red or Red will supercede the Green.

For green you will set `Field Value is equal to "Active"` and change the color.

For Orange You will set `Expression is [Cancellation_date] >= Now()`

For Red You will set `Expression is [Cancellation_date] < Now() Or IsNull([Cancellation_date])`

What it will look like in DataSheet view:

[image]

And What the Formatting rules look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, its a whole new experience for me. but its only working for ACTIVE(green) but not for the rest. I guess its because of the expression

Comment: you need to change the first box in the conditional formatting window from ```Field Value Is``` to ```Expression Is```. If you had already done that, check to make sure your [cancellation_date] is formatted as a date.

Comment: the query field that is being used for the control textbox we are formatting is working based on the IIF conditions I posted earlier, it shows ACTIVE (Which is a string value) if a condition is fulfilled and " cancelled on [cancellation_date]....." (which is a concatenation of string and a value from another field called cancellation_date). The third condition simply says 'cancelled' for the third condition. It works for both active and cancelled but not working for the concatenation.

Comment: The condition I placed should look at that [Cancellation_date] field. The other option is to just set the condition to ```"equal to " & [Cancellation_date].value```

Comment: `status2: IIf([Status]="ACTIVE";"ACTIVE";IIf([Cancellation_date]<Now() Or IsNull([Cancellation_date]);"Cancelled ";"To be cancelled on " & [Cancellation_date] & ""))`       the field values are one of the three: "Active", "cancelled" and "to be cancelled on ...." its working fine for the first two if i set the formation condition to be equal to active and cancelled respectively. Its the third condition that is not working becasue it has to be an expression. its bringing the value but the colouring is missing

Comment: Yeah, so base your condition either on [cancellation_date] or on the value of the field you are setting your condition for.

Comment: its not working based on cancellcation_date and if i want to  base it on the value of the field you are setting your condition for, how do i do it becaue it changes with the value of cancellation_date (its mixture of a string and a variable (date)

Comment: ```Field Value Is equal to "To be cancelled on  " & [Cancellation_date]```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. you helped solved 97 percent of it. but i simply fixed the 3 percent by setting the field value not between active and cancelled.